# URL Rewrite for a subdomain hiding the redirection

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, symfony1

I'm using the symfony framework to do some PHP development, which uses the same code base for separate sites. This requires me to do some htaccess rewriting which is causing me some pain.

The main index page for `developer.mysite.com` is `developer.php`. What I'm trying to is rewrite everything going to `developer.mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com/developer.php/$1`.  However, in the url, I still want it to say `developer.mysite.com/$1`

The following code I have now redirects and doesn't keep the original url:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^developer\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/developer.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aliasing `developer.mysite.com` to `mysite.com` or does it have it's own public_html (or httpdocs; whatever the webroot is...) folder?

I think the easiest solution would be to point `developer.mysite.com` to `mysite.com` on the server so that they share the same public_html folder.

- Your main website's front controller would be something like `main.php`.
- The developer subdomain would have its front controller, `developer.php`.
- `index.php` would look at `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to determine and include the appropriate front controller.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with how symfony operates. I'm assuming it has a front controller like a bazillion other frameworks do.

Comment: simshaun, developer.mysite.com is an alias for www.mysite.com. i'd like to know how to change the url via htaccess.

Comment: So you have a VirtualHost set up for `developer.mysite.com`, e.g. `<VirtualHost developer.mysite.com>` and the DocumentRoot in it points to the main webroot, e.g. `DocumentRoot /home/mysite/public_html`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is better to make separate dir for ur application.
I give an expamle how I realized this task:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/path/to/poject/web"
      ServerName domain.dev

    Alias /sf C:/xampp/php/PEAR/data/symfony/web/sf

    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web">
      #php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 7
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/php/PEAR/data/symfony/web/sf">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/path/to/poject/web_developer"
      ServerName developer.domain.dev

    Alias /sf C:/xampp/php/PEAR/data/symfony/web/sf

    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web_developer">
      #php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 7
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/php/PEAR/data/symfony/web/sf">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>

    Alias /css /path/to/poject/web/css
    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web/css">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    Alias /images /path/to/poject/web/images
    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web/images">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    Alias /js /path/to/poject/web/js
    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web/js">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    Alias /sfDoctrinePlugin /path/to/poject/web/sfDoctrinePlugin
    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web/sfDoctrinePlugin">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    Alias /sfFormExtraPlugin /path/to/poject/web/sfFormExtraPlugin
    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web/sfFormExtraPlugin">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
    Alias /uploads /path/to/poject/web/uploads
    <Directory "/path/to/poject/web/uploads">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

`web_developer` dir is usual web dir of sf1.4 project

Comment: While that's a great solve, im trying to do this with rewriting the url.